# Identify and highlight duplicate records in Excel sheet using EPPlus library

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

For example, I have a sheet called EmployeeSheet, which is having multiple columns like FirstName, LastName, Address etc.. and needs to identify the duplicates records based on several columns then apply highlighter with comments to the entire row.  And let's assume this list is perfectly formatted and has no duplicates so every cell is unique in this sheet.

Here's the solution I can think of but not able to figure out how to implement and always returns true.

```
public static bool HasDuplicates(string path)
{
    List<object> allObjects = new List<object>();

    using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path)))
    {
        // Go through all sheets
        foreach (var sheet in excel.Workbook.Worksheets)
        {
            // Go through all cells
            foreach (var cell in sheet.Cells)
            {
                // Ignore null cells
                if(cell.Value != null)
                {
                    if (allObjects.Contains(cell.Value))
                        return true;
                    allObjects.Add(cell.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the columns you need to check for duplicates?

Comment: i found solution to this issue, thanks for your help